# How do I inject a HazelcastInstance to a MapStoreFactory

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using a `MapStore` backed implementation. I would want to invoke the `init(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance, Properties properties, String mapName)` method of the `MapStore` to inject the Hz instance from the factory.

In order to achieve that, I tried making the `MapStoreFactory` implement `HazelcastInstanceAware`, however that did not work.

I need the hazelcastInstance since I want to make my MapStore, a `MapListener` as well. Is this something achievable?

Thanks,
Sutanu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was invoking the `init(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance, Properties properties, String mapName)` method from the `MapStoreFactory`. This was incorrect. Removing it made things work.